# Mirgration of questions to U&L

Tags: support, migration

On reflection I feel that I should have posted the following three questions of mine on U&L rather than SF.  Can they please be migrated?

- [How to block a specific GID via PAM?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1122842/how-to-block-a-specific-gid-via-pam)
- [Can authconfig/authselect only be used with PAM modules known by authconfig/authselect?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1122837/can-authconfig-authselect-only-be-used-with-pam-modules-known-by-authconfig-auth)
- [Overwriting exisitng gidNumber with GID of group of which users is a member](https://serverfault.com/questions/1111593/overwriting-exisitng-gidnumber-with-gid-of-group-of-which-users-is-a-member)

Comment: Ward 's answer is the best approach as one thing to remember here is that a migration don't change the timestamp. So your questions if migrated might loose visibility as they will be listed with older questions.

Comment: Additionally, you can rewrite questions so they may get better answers more topically. I tend to think of SF as being for "something is wrong when the things are trying to do something together (as a system)" and U&L being for "I don't get the thing."

Answer (score 1):

In general, migration can be problematic, so a better approach in this case would be to have your questions closed here (done) and then re-ask them on Unix & Linux.